# Counting no.of text files under a directory in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have a folder /mqlocal/mqm. inside that there are 2 text files 
(bindu.txt,sujitha.txt). I need code to count the number of text files under the directory. The result should be an integer.

Comment: Is the result always going to be zero, one or two depending on whether those two files exist or not, or may there be other files that you also want to count?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
find /mqlocal/mqm -type f -iname "*.txt" | wc -l
```

`-type f`: It is for finding files. It will ignore the directories inside `/mqlocal/mqm` directory.

`-iname`: It will match only files ending with `.txt`. `-i` is for Case insensitive.

`wc -l`: It will count the number of files.

Comment: No, `wc -l` will count the number of _lines_ outputted by `find`. To make this the number of _files_, use `-exec echo x \;` to output a line for each file. If you don't, you would count filenames containing newlines as multiple files.

Answer (score -1):

find *.txt | wc -l

change the present working directory to /mqlocal/mqm, and then execute the command.

It will gives you the count of the text files in that directory.

Comment: Try that with a file that you create with `touch $'file\nname.txt'` in an otherwise empty directory.